# Can we build some sort of ventilation system in our rental apartment?

Tags: exhaust-fan

There isn't an exhaust fan in our kitchen. Everytime we fry or bake something we set off the smoke detector.
There's a window pretty close to our kitchen.  Is there a way to rig up some sort of flexible exhaust tubing and a fan so that we can draw the smoke out our window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it sufficient to put a window fan in the window when cooking?

If not, there are **ductless range hoods**, also known as **recirculating range hoods**.  These filter the air and lets it back out in the room.

Comment: I think the recirculating range hood might work out really well.  Thanks!